# Backup localhost (wamp) database (phpmyadmin) from harddrive files on windows? For WordPress?

Tags: backup, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to backup files from a old hard drive without having access to phpmyadmin? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what do you have access to? just files?

Comment: Yes, I have the entire www file saved in the wamp folder locally on my computer. I want to know where the database for all of the WordPress Database files are so I can move to another HardDrive.

Comment: The files are located here. \wamp\bin\MySQL\mysql...\data thanks to Grant H for the help. Ok, So I found the files but how do I import these table files to the database? I've done heaps of Google searching buy can't seem to find the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it's the best way but her is **a** very simple way to do it:

1. Install a new copy of WAMP.
2. Copy the files from the old HD to you newly installed wamp
   `\bin\mysql\mysql...\data` folder.
3. Log in to phpmyadmin (that comes  with WAMP) and create a dump of
   the database

Comment: How do I create a dump of the database?

Comment: In phpmyadmin you have an export option.